# How to use PyGitHib repo.create_file

Tags: python, github

I am trying to use PyGitHub to automate updating files in a special repository.  This special repo consists of parts of several other repos so I am using a GitHub webhook to cause it to be updated whenever any of the other repos are updated.  I am running into a problem when a file is added to any of the other repos.  In this case, I need to add a file to the special repo.  Here is a snippet of the code

```
from github import GitHub

ACCESS_TOKEN = '...'
ORGANIZATION = '...'
REPONAME     = '...'

gh = Github(ACCESS_TOKEN)
org = gh.get_organization(ORGANIZATION)
repo = org.get_repo(REPONAME)
path = <path-to-file-in-special-repo>
message = <commit-message-for-create-file>
contents = OtherRepo.get_contents(<<path-to-file-in-other-repo>).decoded_content.decode('utf-8')
repo.create_file(path, message, contents)
```

This is giving me the following error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<string>", line 1, in <module>
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/github/Repository.py", line 2090, in create_file
    headers, data = self._requester.requestJsonAndCheck(
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/github/Requester.py", line 353, in requestJsonAndCheck
    return self.__check(
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/github/Requester.py", line 378, in __check
    raise self.__createException(status, responseHeaders, output)
github.GithubException.GithubException: 422 {"message": "Invalid request.\n\n\"sha\" wasn't supplied.", "documentation_url": "https://docs.github.com/rest/reference/repos#create-or-update-file-contents"}
```

If I just do:
repo.create_file(path, 'test', 'test')
it works.

Can anyone tell me what I am doing wrong?

Answer (score 0):

I have discovered what the problem is.

Because of the way I was testing my program the file I was trying to create was one previously deleted from the repo.  What I needed to do was repo.update_file and, not repo.create_file.